# In class of 5 students with random grades, what is the probability that 2 or more have the same grade?

Tags: probability

If 5 students were given a random grade, (A, B, C, D, F), then what is the possibility of at least two of them having the same grade?

Comment: Hint: First find the probability they all have different grades.

Comment: @AndréNicolas There's only one possible combination in which they can all have different grades, but now how do I figure out the total number possible combinations?

Comment: This is a permutation rather than a combination.  The outcome that Anne receives an A and Brenda receives a B is different than Brenda receives an A and Anne receives a B.

Comment: Student 1 can have 5 possible grades.  Student 2 can have 5 grades.  The total number of options is 5x5.  Each student can have 5 possible grades so the total number of options is 5x5x5 5x5 =$5^5$.

Comment: @medyns there are more than one way to have different grades.  There are $5!$ ways to assign five distinct grades, one to each of five students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line up the students in order of weight, and call the students Student 1, Student 2, and so on.

Assume grades are assigned at random and independently. (This assumption is quite unreasonable, but let us hold our noses and go on.)

The probability Student 2 has a different grade from Student 1 is $4/5$. Given these two have different grades, the probability Student 3 has a new grade is $3/5$. And so on, for a probability of $(4/5)(3/5)(2/5)(1/5)$.

Finally, subtract this number from $1$.

*Another way*: There are $5^5$ equally likely (?) assignments of grades. For there are $5^5$ five-letter words that can be formed using the letters A, B, C, D, F.

There are $5!$ words in which the letters  are all different. (These are the *permutations* of our five ltters.)

So the probability all the students have different grades is $\frac{5!}{5^5}$.